# Initialized array by indices of elements in ascending order

Tags: c

I have 2 arrays in C program. A1, A2 with size 1500, 780 respectively. Type of each array is
integer (int). How can I initialized A1 by the indices of elements in ascending order, A2 - by the indices too, but in descending order?.

```
int A1[1500]
int A2[780]
```

Comment: Have you learnt `for` or `while` loops yet? Just need use either loop and an incrementing or decrementing counter. If not done already, suggest you read a basic C tutorial or book, attempt some code and come back to show the code if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define SIZE1   1500
#define SIZE2   780


int main(void)
{
    int i, A1[SIZE1], A2[SIZE2];

    // from i = 0 to i = SIZE1-1
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
        A1[i] = i;

    // from i = SIZE2-1 to i = 0
    for (i = SIZE2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        A2[i] = i;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please note that you should `#define` constants (in this case, the size of statically declared arrays).

Comment: Thank you. Do you kno why my code have error?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SZ_A1 1500
#define SZ_A2 780
#define SZ_A3 950
 
int main(void) {
 int i, A1[SZ_A1], A2[SZ_A2];
 
    // from i = 0 to i = SZ_A1-1
    for (i = 0; i < SZ_A1; i++)
        A1[i] = i;
 
    // from i = SZ_A2-1 to i = 0
    for (i = SZ_A2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        A2[i] = i;
 
 int* A3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * SZ_A3);
 memcpy(A3, A1, sizeof(int) * SZ_A3);
 memcpy(A3 + SZ_A3 / 2 + 1, A2, sizeof(int) * (SZ_A3 / 2));
 printf("%i", *(A3 + (SZ_A3 / 2)));
 return 0;
}